# Can anyone embed Unity app in React Native project?

Tags: react-native, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I have an augmented reality project. It will be a mobile app and I need to access the Unity app from within the app. Are there any react native libraries that you know are up-to-date?

There is webgl library for reactjs. But this library is not applicable for React Native.